# How to create multiple records and handle validations with create method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create multiple records at once but if there are any record which was not created because of any validation error then it should handle that error in some way.

**PARAMETERS**

```
  Parameters: {"group"=>[{"sort_by"=>"id", "template_ids"=>[182], "name"=>"Csdfwses", "count"=>1}, {"sort_by"=>"id", "template_ids"=>[181], "name"=>"rthydrt", "count"=>1}]}
```

So my controller's `create` method is like this:

```
def create
  @groups = Group.create group_params
   if @groups
    render json: { success: true, message: "#{@groups.length} groups created" }
   else
    render_422 @groups, 'Could not save groups.'
   end
end
```

i want to handle the case if there is any error occurred while creating  any record such that after creating it should display the error message.

With the above approach there is no way to use `error` method here. How to show the error messages?

I tried using [begin-rescue](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html):

```
 def create
  begin
   @groups = Group.create! group_params
    if @groups
     render json: { success: true, message: "#{@groups.length} groups created" }
    else
     render_422 @groups, 'Could not save groups.'
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    render json: { success: false, message: "#{invalid.record.errors.messages}" }, status: 500
  end
 end
```

But i'm looking for the cleaner approach if there is any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to pass an array of hashes to `model.create` to create multiple records at once.

```
def create
  @groups = Group.create group_params
   if @groups.all? { |group| group.persisted? }
    render json: { success: true, message: "#{@groups.length} groups created" }
   else
    render_422 @groups, 'Could not save groups.'
   end
end
```

If you want to display any validation errors, then you will want to look in `model.errors` or for a nice array of errors you can look at `model.errors.full_messages`.

```
def create
  @groups = Group.create group_params
   if @groups.all? { |group| group.persisted? }
    render json: { success: true, message: "#{@groups.length} groups created" }
   else
    errors = @groups.select(&:invalid?).map{ |g| g.errors.full_messages }.join("<br/>") 
    render_422 @groups, "Could not save groups. Here are the errors: #{errors}"
   end
end
```

You will want to format the errors better, but this is a simple example.

Comment: Its a pretty muddy question but I think he is looking to create several Group records at once - this would only create a single record.

Comment: Yes i want to create several groups at once. I tried to use `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid` and displaying the messages like this `render json: { success: false, message: "#{invalid.record.errors.messages}" }, status: 500`

Comment: I answered that question. However, I did it in a really ugly way, and you will want to figure out what format you want your errors in. Likely you will want to keep track of which group object had the error so it's easier for the user to fix the mistake.

Comment: Good luck on your project :)

Answer (score 6):

You would normally use `accepts_nested_attributes` - but this requires some sort of hierarchical relation:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  accepts_nested_records_for :employees
  validates_associated :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  validates_presence_of :name
end

c = Company.new(name: 'Acme', employee_attributes: [
  { name: 'Wile E. Coyotee' },
  { name: 'Bugs Bunny' },
  { name: nil } # invalid
])

c.valid? # false
c.save # false
```

So how would you do this without a parent model? Create a model that acts like a parent association:

```
# A fake parent model for groups.
# This is not a ActiveRecord model
# It's is not backed by a database table.
class GroupCollection
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :groups

  def initialize(groups_attributes: [], **kw_args)
    super
  end

  # mimics behavior of accepts_nested_attributes
  # takes either an array or a key/val hash:
  # { 1 => {'name' => 'foo'} }
  def groups_attributes=(attrs)
     # normalize key/val hash
     attrs = attrs.values if attrs.is_a?(Hash)
     self.groups = attrs.map {|h| Group.new(h) }
  end

  # mimics behavior of validates_associated
  def valid?
    errors.clear
    # alternatively you can aggregate errors for
    # the nested records on the parent object
    if groups.reject { |g| g.valid? }.any?
      errors.add(:groups, 'are invalid.')
    end
    errors.none?
  end

  def save
    return false unless valid?
    save_in_transaction
  end

  def save!
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid and return unless valid?
    save_in_transaction
  end

  private 
    def save_in_transaction
      # use a transaction so changes are rolled back if a save fails.
      Group.transaction do
        groups.reject { |g| g.save! }.none? 
      end
    end
end
```

---

```
class GroupsController

  def create
    @collection = GroupCollection.new(groups_params)
    @groups = @collection.groups

    if @collection.save
      c = @groups.length
      render json: { 
            success: true, # anti-pattern! - rely on the response code instead
            message: "#{c} #{pluralize(c, 'group')} created" 
      }, status: :created
    else
      # you can get the error messages by iterating through @groups
      # and calling `.errors.full_messages` on each
      render_422 @groups, 'Could not save groups.'
    end
  end

  def collection_params
    params.permit(groups_attributes: [:name, :foo, :bar])
  end
end
```

Comment: how would you handle uniqueness constraint with this? If it had `uniqueness: true` for company's name then it would raise an exception on `GroupCollection#save!`

Comment: Thats why you use `.save` and not `.save!` in your normal controller flow.  `.save!` should only really be used when your invoking it from the shell and need direct feedback or when you are wrapping multiple saves in a transaction and need it to roll back if the records are invalid.

Comment: You can use [`validates_associated`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) to make the parent validate each of the nested records.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Why `*args` and `**kw_args` in `initialize` methods. Also, why `super` in `initialize`?

Comment: To answer my own question: *Also, if for some reason you need to run code on initialize, make sure you call super if you want the attributes hash initialization to happen.* Ref: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html

Comment: Exactly, although `*args` is not really needed here as the initializer only takes a hash.  `**kw_args` slurps the rest of the hash arguments passed to the class. Its a newer Ruby 2.0 syntax which does about the same thing as `initialize(kw_args = { groups_attributes: [] })`